# What's the density of a frozen ethanol or ethanol solutions?

Tags: water, solutions, phase, density

How can we know what's the density of ice (water), but there's no data on how much is the density of frozen ethanol? (as far as I know)

Comment: You've probably seen water ice quite a number of times. Frozen ethanol, on the other hand, requires going well beyond $-100^\circ\rm C$, which you probably don't do every day. That said, I believe the data is somewhere out there, only it's not that easy to come by.

Comment: The closest online source I found, http://www.celsius-process.com/pdf/ethanol.pdf , only goes to 4K above ethanol's m.p.  It does seem that not *all* reference material is readily found online... yet.